# Using MakeLowercase and StrSubstitute together

Tags: macros, xstring

I'm using LaTeX and have a string that I want to remove underscores from, and convert to lower case (in either order). The individual steps work:

```
\MakeLowercase{AB\_CD} \StrSubstitute{AB\_CD}{\_}{}
```

yields

```
ab_cd ABCD
```

but I get errors for either:

```
\StrSubstitute{\MakeLowercase{AB\_CD}}{\_}{}
```

or:

```
\MakeLowercase{\StrSubstitute{AB\_CD}{\_}{}}
```

I need to do this in a LaTeX macro, and put the result of this (lower-cased and underscore-stripped) to be usable as an argument to another command, or to be captured into a variable for such use.

Evidently I don't understand how macro substitution really works, but I can't seem to find a good explanation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thanks Markus!  I hope to become proficient with LaTeX and use it for most of my documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stringstrings` package is slow and has other problems, but here it can do what you ask:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\def\x{AB\_CD}Was: \x

\caselower[e]{\x}
\convertchar[q]{\thestring}{\_}{}
IS: \retokenize[v]{\thestring}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using `T1` encoding, it is easier still.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\def\x{AB\_CD}Was: \x
\caselower[e]{\x}
IS: \convertchar[v]{\thestring}{\_}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works pretty well for me. I don't mind if it's slow, but is there somewhere I can read about the "other problems" you referenced?

Comment: @EricSmith It was one of the earliest packages I wrote, when I knew very little about LaTeX.  So I did things very inefficiently.  I don't recall the details, but one user reported a conflict with another package.  The package has the ability but only in a very limited way, to process macros in its arguments.  If you are sticking to manipulating pure text and character macros like `\_`, etc., it should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

`\MakeLowercase` *expands* its argument to get the string to lowercase, but the string replace you are using does not work by expansion. Here though you don't really need a string replace, just locally make `\_` expand to nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\_{}\MakeLowercase{AB\_CD}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That might be workable, but how to I get the original definition of \_ back?  For instance, if I use it in a command: `\newcommand{\munge}[1]{
  \renewcommand\_{}\MakeLowercase{#1}
}`

Comment: @EricSmith it is a local redefinition, the original definition is restored at the `}` at the end of the line shown. Your `\newcommand` would want `{}` around the setting as in `\newcommand{\munge}[1]{ {\renewcommand\_{}\MakeLowercase{#1}} }`

Answer (score 3):

Do it in two separate steps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute{AB\_CD}{\_}{}[\SUBtemp]\MakeLowercase{\SUBtemp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some fundamental limitation in the way that macros (or commands, or whatever they are) work that requires the use of the temporary variable rather than directly using the result of one as the argument of the other?

Comment: @EricSmith Yes: `\lowercase` doesn't *execute* what's passed to it and `\MakeLowercase` adds a layer over it. So `\lowercase{\StrSubstitute{AB\_CD}{\_}{}}` would work by lowercasing before doing `\StrSubstitute`, but with `\MakeLowercase` this is not possible, because basically it scans its input token by token applying `\lowercase` when needed.

Comment: I didn't originally state it in the question, but I need to use the output of \MakeLowercase as an argument to something else, either directly or via another temporary variable, and I can't seem to do that. My failed attempt:
`\newcommand{\munge}[1]{
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{\_}{}[\SUBtemp]
  \def\SUBtemp2{\MakeLowercase{\SUBtemp}}
  \SomeOtherRandomCommand{\SUBtemp2}
}`

Comment: @EricSmith You can't pass the output of `\MakeLowercase` to any macro: what it produces is just for printing, more or less. Do you really need `\MakeLowercase` because of accents or are your strings just letters and simple commands like `\_`?

Answer (score 2):

With an up-to-date `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \LowerCase \text_lowercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrSubstitute{\LowerCase{AB\_CD}}{\_}{}
\end{document}
```

This works because `\text_lowercase:n` in `expl3` does *not* use `\lowercase` and so is expandable (contrast with the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209891/using-makelowercase-and-strsubstitute-together#comment490652_209896) on egreg's answer).

Comment: In principle I like the idea of being forward-looking and using expl3, even if the details may change in the future. However, at the moment I'm struggling with LaTeX 2, so I'm not sure I want to throw LaTeX 3 stuff into the mix.